# jQuery Tooltip Custom Tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am trying to have a custom tooltip for my images when the user hovers over them using jQuery Tool's [Tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/#configuration). In the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/haochi/Utbcb/1/) you will see two rows. The top row is using the custom tip option, whereas the bottom row uses the regular title attribute.

As you can see, the tooltip sticks around when you mouse over them while the ones on the top row using the custom tip disappears when the mouse moves away from the image. They don't have an example in their documentation for this specific option so I am not exactly sure how it is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might just be a edge case in the tooltip code... they don't expect you to use the same custom content in every tooltip. But, if you make three divs with content and point the tooltips to each different one, it works as expected ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Utbcb/3/)):